# Primary Key Violation (duplicate key value?)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a program that **adds/edits/deletes** products from a database.

Everything else works great, but whenever I try to **add** a new product (testing with '1234'), I get a `primary key violation` error.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Products'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object     'dbo.Products'. The duplicate key value is
>   (1234    ). The statement has been terminated.

This product number most definitely does not already exist, and still doesn't exist when I search for it afterwards.

Can anyone help me figure out what may be causing this? I am not able to pinpoint the issue.

This is my `AddProduct` method.

```
public static bool AddProduct(Product product)
{
    SqlConnection connect = MMABooksDB.GetConnection();
    string insert = "INSERT Products (ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice) VALUES (@code, @description, @price)";
    SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insert, connect);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", product.Code);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", product.Description);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", product.Price);
         try
            {
                connect.Open();
                int counter = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string selectStatement =
                    "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Products') FROM Products";
                SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connect);
                 int ProductCode;
                object dbProductID = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
             if (dbProductID != null || dbProductID != DBNull.Value)
                    ProductCode = 0;
                else
                    ProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(dbProductID);
                if (counter>0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
}
```

And this is the `Product` class

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string code;
        public string description;
        public decimal price;

        public Product() { }

        public Product(string code, string description, decimal price)
        {
            this.Code = code;
            this.Description = description;
            this.Price = price;
        }

        public string Code
        {
            get
            {
                return code;
            }
            set
            {
                code = value;
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return description;
            }
            set
            {
                description = value;
            }
        }

        public decimal Price
        {
            get
            {
                return price;
            }
            set
            {
                price = value;
            }
        }

        public string GetDisplayText()
        {
            return code + ", " + price.ToString("c") + ", " + description;
        }

        public string GetDisplayText(string sep)
        {
            return code + sep + price.ToString("c") + sep + description;
        }
    }
}
```

You guys have already helped me with this program once tonight, and I am very grateful. Thank you for any insight you can provide. Please let me know if any further information would be useful.

Comment: whats your primary key, is it `AUTO`?

Comment: My primary key is the ProductCode field

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown? Just to be sure.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick: making assumptions about IDENTITY](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity) in which he also explains why you should **stay away** from `IDENT_CURRENT`

Comment: Patrick, while running through the debugger for the ~5th time to get you the line number, I finally figured out what was happening. In another part of my code, I was calling the AddProduct method twice. As it ran through the second time, it was finding the ProductCode that resulted from the first run through. I'm sorry it ended up being something so simple, but thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, as far as I can see, no value in your insert for the primary key (usually called `id`).

I guess you did not use some sort of auto incrementing on that field.

Comment: The ProductCode field is the primary key in this instance. No auto incrementing. While I agree that would work, I'm just trying to figure out why my program is throwing the code in the first place. My database does not contain a "1234" ProductCode, but it says its a duplicate when I try and insert that code?

Comment: Maybe something unrelated but the error message says '1234 '. Note the space.

Answer (score 2):

I geuss you forgot to do you productcode +1 somewhere. Why aren't you using auto increment on you pk? That will work any time.

Comment: I'm allowing the user to enter the product code for the new products, so the pk can't be auto incremented. However, I'm getting this error even when the new product code is unique from any codes already in the database.

Comment: I would use a technical pk field and a functional field code which can be set by the user. Make business rule to check for duplicate codes. In this case the db is probably not lying to you. However the sample code only gives the opportunity to do some wild guesses